# wait for subscribe to finish and call save in angular6?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I have to complete validation functions before calling the save function. I am calling API (Async in C#) for validation function and it does not wait until the return result and proceeding in to save which is wrong.

```
submit() {        
       this.validateBeforeSave();
       this.Save();        
      }
    
     validateBeforeSave()
     {
      // Here calling API action ( used Async and Await in C#)
          forkJoin([Action1URL, Action2URL])             
        .subscribe(([Action1Data, Action2Data]) => {
           this.ValidateData(
              Action1Data,
              Action2Data
            );
           // Don't want to call save here. should be called separately.
        });   
     }
     
     Save()
     {
     // Saving data.
     
     }
```

Please let me know how to wait for the return result from the subscribe and then call the save function? And how can I call save function without placing inside subscribe ?

Comment: `ValidateData` will this function have impact if save will be called or not, and do you need `Action1Data, Action2Data`  for save operation

Comment: You can't do that.  The solution is you should have to store your subscription into promise or subscription and then on your save method you can call and subscribe or use then ("if you use promise") to get the result before saving.

Comment: @vaira : No , I am not using Action1Data, Action2Data for save operation..

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula : How to get result before call saving  ?

Comment: what about `ValidateData' does it return a boolean that true or false that tells you that you should or should not save?

Comment: @vaira :  subscribe is not waiting for result whether true (or) false.. If I set return value boolean for ValidateData and default it is false then it gives false always because the result might not be getting at that time.

Comment: @ANR read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Validate method returns a boolean that lets you know if you should save or not.

```
submit() {
      this.validateBeforeSave()
        .subscribe((isFormValid: boolean) => {
          if (isFormValid) { // depending on result of ValidateData
            this.Save();
          }
        });
    }
    
    validateBeforeSave(): Observable < boolean > { // returns observable
      // Here calling API action ( used Async and Await in C#)
      forkJoin([Action1URL, Action2URL])
      .pipe(map([Action1Data, Action2Data]) => {
        return this.ValidateData(Action1Data, Action2Data); // returning boolean returned from validateData
      });
    }
    
    Save() {
      // Saving data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call save() function separately after subscribe, While it hits subscribe it will redirect to next line after execution of all lines next to validateBeforeSave() function and then code inside subscribe will be executed.

---

```
submit() {        
       this.validateBeforeSave();
      
      }
    
     validateBeforeSave()
     {
      // Here calling API action ( used Async and Await in C#)
          forkJoin([Action1URL, Action2URL])             
        .subscribe(([Action1Data, Action2Data]) => {
           this.ValidateData(
              Action1Data,
              Action2Data
            );
           this.Save();        
        });   
     }
     
     Save()
     {
     // Saving data.
     
     }
```

Comment: Yes but you can return an observable from the method and subscribe outside 'validateBeforeSave', which is what the OP wants, to not have save operation inside the  `validateBeforeSave` function